# Can I use pyodbc executemany with sql stored procedure?

Tags: python, t-sql, stored-procedures, pyodbc, executemany

I need to write a lot of data from pandas dataframes to MS-SQL tables (1000's or even more rows at once).

I'm using `pyodbc executmany` with `fast_executemany=True`, otherwise it takes hours for each table. Now the IT guys want me to start working with stored procedures instead of direct access to the DB for security reasons.

The problem is that from what I've seen, SQL is, how to say, not as flexible as python, and I have to declare every variable passed to the SP, so I don't see how I can pass the SP with `df.values.tolist()` as I'm doing today with the `executemany` function on direct access to the DB.

For example, let's say I have a dataframe df:

### id    name    salary

1     Josh    10000

2     Michael  5000

3     Sara     8000

Today I would use:

```
cursor.fast_executemany = True
insert_str = "INSERT INTO [%s].[%s] VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
cursor.executemany(insert_str % (scheme, table), df.values.tolist()])
```

And all the dataframe would be inserted to the table at once (and fast). But, is doesn't seem possible to do the same with calling an SP.

Is there a way to use `pyodbc executemany` with stored procedures?

Comment: "I have to declare every variable passed to the SP" not necessarily. If your SP only has input parameters and the columns in your DataFrame correspond to those input parameters *in the exact same order* then the ODBC `{CALL yourSp(?,?,...)}` syntax should work fine. Please [edit] your question with a simple example of what you are trying to accomplish and any errors (or unexpected results) that you receive.

Comment: Tnx. I've edited, with an example of the need. Didn't try to to the same with {CALL mySp(?, ?, ?)}, as I don't see where the df.values.tolist() fits.

Comment: The first thing I'd try would be `cursor.executemany("{CALL mySp(?, ?, ?)}", df.values.tolist())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we can use `executemany` with Stored Procedures in SQL Server:

Table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [salary] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Stored Procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Table_1_insert] 
    @id int = 0, 
    @name nvarchar(50),
    @salary int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO Table_1 (id, name, salary) VALUES (@id, @name, @salary);
END
```

Python code:

```python
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [(1, 'Josh', 10000), (2, 'Michael', 5000), (3, 'Sara', 8000)], 
    columns=['id', 'name', 'salary'])
crsr.executemany("{CALL dbo.Table_1_insert(?, ?, ?)}", df.values.tolist())
cnxn.commit()
```